# deferred event in Socket.io event

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I am implementing a socket.io chat system and would like to find out a way to address a problem I am facing.

```
socket.on("private message", message => {
        let nome = $.post("/endpoints/getNomeChat.php", {
            userID: message.from
        }, function(data) {
            const currentUrl = reqPath.split('?');
            if (currentUrl[0] == "chat.php") {
                //if this is true I have to modify some elements of the DOM
                //that have been added to the DOM with ajax
                $('.addedElement').append(data);
                //will not work since `.addedElement` has been added later to the DOM
            }
```

So the point is that if the `if` evaluates to true I want to manipulate some elements of the DOM that where not there on page load but have been added later to the page. Normaly I'd use jquery `.on` to do this but here I have no event to pass to `.on` and thus I am stucked.

How can I solve this?